# Creating PHP website but all data retrieved through JAVA local webservices?

Tags: java, php, web-services, rest, localhost

My plan is to set up a php-based website except all the dynamic data would be loaded through a local RESTful webservice.

The local RESTful webservices would be created using Java Jersey, which will access a MySQL database. The reason behind this is because I would like all the logic to be handled by Java.

Would this perform poorly? I have created RESTful services before and created php websites but never used them together...would calling a webservice on localhost be a terrible way to set this up?

Comment: much greater overhead than any 'standard' set up; may or may not work depending on (quite a lot of things).

Comment: Is there any other reason to implement these web services apart from access to MySQL?

Comment: The people i'm working with have experience in java only, it would speed up development. I guess going full php would be my only solution here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and no. If you plan to extend this beyond a website, e.g. if you plan to have other applications consume your web services, then I'd say it would be an appropriate design. Otherwise, no need for the overhead.

Comment: Is there any other protocol besides HTTP (restful) that would allow me to communicate efficiently between my webserver and my java application?

Comment: The other widely used protocol would be SOAP, but it has more overhead, so I'd stick to rest in your case, especially since you've done other web services